# Get current Office theme

Tags: c#, ms-office

In a C# app I'd like to programmatically find the current theme for Office 2013 (White/Light Gray/Dark Gray). Surprisingly I'm not able to find much discussion on this and from what I have read it should be in a Theme folder in the registry, however my registry doesn't contain a Theme folder at the suggested path.

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668248/office-2010-addin-development-can-i-from-code-behind-read-what-theme-the-user), but the Theme folder doesn't exist.

**note** I'm using Office 2013 on Windows 8.1

**update** Using @Dai's suggestion I found the values for 2007/10/13`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\X.0\Common\[Theme or UI Theme]`

In Office 2007/2010 the value is `Theme` where as in 2013 they changed it to `UI Theme`.

If Office is using the default theme and you've never changed it these keys will NOT exist so keep that in mind if you can't find them. Upon changing the theme Office will write these keys.

Comment: To find out where it's stored, try using Process Monitor and watching what happens to your system when you change the setting in real-life.

Comment: That did the trick. If you want to create an answer I'll accept it and add the path where I ultimately found it.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't personally know myself, but you can often easily find out where any application's configuration/settings/data are stored by using Sysinternals Process Monitor ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx ) and watching the process write somewhere (a file, the registry, etc) when you effect a change.

1. Load Process Monitor
2. Set a filter to watch winword.exe
3. Open Word
4. Clear the current Process Monitor history (as there will be a lot of useless data displayed from when the Word process loaded)
5. Go File > Options > Theme (change it to something else)
6. Watch and see what appears in the window
7. If nothing appears, you're living in a universe with causality violations

Actually, there are some DRM systems, for example, that store state via a Windows system driver or rootkit that would not appear in Process Monitor (as the operation happens in the kernel), or worse: raw disk writes.